# Why the last SPLIT function causes SEGMENTATION FAULT? How to fix this

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, doubly-linked-list

I wrote the typical program for the doubly-linked list in circular buffer (here: RING). I am using iterators (I have to, school project).

All seem to work, but there is something with the memory, and I can't find a way to fix it somehow. Probably the reason of segmentation fault is that I am accessing the "forbidden" part.

**Whole code** [HERE](https://ideone.com/63i8rk)

The problem is I can't find the place I should fix it.

Function SPLIT:
made two separate circular buffers from the original circular buffer.

For the 1st one I start iterating from the 1st position, for the 2nd- from the 2nd position. DIR means clockwise (if true), otherwise- false. LEN means the length of the RING we want to obtain. 
We iterate every second element.

In snipped code you got real example.

```
/******* external function ********/
/****** Example of the split function:
split (r3,r1,true,3,r2,false,6)
r3= 1,2,3,4,5
r1= 1,3,5
r2= 2,5,3,1,4,2
********/

template <typename Key>
Ring<Key> split(const Ring<Key> &source,Ring<Key> &result1, bool dir1, int len1, Ring<Key> &result2, bool dir2, int len2){

typename Ring<Key>::iterator i1 = source.begin();
typename Ring<Key>::iterator i2 = source.begin();
/*I moved second iterator to the 2nd position in original Ring*/
i2++;


if (source.isEmpty()){
    cout<<"Empty source Ring"<<endl;}

if (source.length()==1||source.length()==2){
    return source;
        }

if((len1 <= 0) || (len2 <= 0))
{
    cout << "split():(incorrect lengths)" << endl;
}

    if(!i1.isNULL()){
        for(int i = 0; i < len1; i++)
        {
            result1.insertLast(i1.getKey());
            if(dir1){
                i1++;
                i1++;;
                }
            else
                {i1--;
                i1--;
                }}}
cout<<result1;

    if(!i2.isNULL()){
        for(int i = 0; i < len2; i++)
        {
            result2.insertLast(i2.getKey());
           if(dir2){
                i2++;
                i2++;
                }
            else
                {i2--;
                i2--;
                }}}
cout<<result2;}
```

Comment: You need to post an [mcve] in the actual question.   You reduce all the code in your "whole code" example (which is almost certainly 80%+ unrelated) until you can't remove anymore without the error going away, then you put that code directly in the question.  Having you guess at where the problem is isn't useful because you don't understand why you're having a problem.   The spot where it crashes doesn't mean it's the spot where the problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I forked your code here: https://ideone.com/7af6D7

Corrected some bits. It no longer segfaults, seemingly, but I dunno if it does what you expect it to do. Read the notes on the comments. You should also specify whether you're working with C++11 or greater or old C++ code (I'm sorry if that's the case)

This should be catched by the compiler in forms of warnings at the very least (you should compile with `-Werror` flag).

Also, please indent your code properly.

Anyway, I dunno why are you returning a copy of the whole source on split function (it should return `void` and `throw` in error or a `bool`).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

template <typename Key>
class Ring
{
    struct Node
    {
        Key key;
        Node *next= nullptr; // Always initialize. Worst case if you do it 
                             // twice: the compiler will be smart enough to 
                             // remove one of the occurrences
        Node *prev= nullptr; // Ditto
    };
    Node *any= nullptr; // Use nullptr on C++11 and onwards
    // Also, any is not a very good name, prefer using root or first

public:

/******* iterator class methods definitions ********/
    class iterator
    {
        Node *el= nullptr; // Ditto
    public:
        iterator()= default; // or iterator() {}
        ~iterator()= default; // or ~iterator() {}

        constexpr iterator(const iterator& copyIter)
        : el(copyIter.el)
        {
            // Empty constructor gets to be constexpr
            // Improves optimizing and can be evaluated at runtime
        }

        constexpr iterator(Node *copyEl)
        : el(copyEl)
        {
        }

        iterator &operator = (const iterator &copyIter)
        {
            el = copyIter.el;
            return *this;
        }

        bool operator == (const iterator &comp) const
        {
            return el == comp.el;
        }

        bool operator != (const iterator &comp) const
        {
            return el != comp.el;
        }

        /* I don't think this operator is good practice
        iterator operator + (const unsigned int number) const
        {
            iterator new_iter = *this; // Could be auto new_iter = *this in C++11
            for(int i = 0; i < number; i++) { // Style: Always put brackets
                new_iter++;
            }
            return new_iter;
        }*/

        iterator& operator ++ ()
        {
            if (el) {
                el = el->next;
            }
            return *this;
            // You had no return if it's null
            // Also, no need for != nullptr or != NULL
            // Usually, you return a reference to self
        }

        iterator operator ++ (int)
        {
            iterator copy_iter(el);
            if (el) {
                el = el->next;
            }
            return copy_iter; // You return the copy, no matter what
        }

        /* Ditto
        iterator operator - (const unsigned int number) const
        {
            iterator new_iter = *this;
            for(int i = 0; i < number; i++) {
                new_iter--;
            }
            return new_iter;
        }*/

        iterator& operator --()
        {
            if (el) {
                el = el->prev;
            }
            return *this;
        }

        iterator operator -- (int)
        {
            iterator copy_iter(el);
            if (el) {
                el= el->prev;
            }
            return copy_iter;
        }

        Key getKey() const
        {
            if (el) {
                return el->key;
            }
            cerr << "getKey(): (iterator = NULL)" << endl;
            return Key(); // Empty element, might aswell throw here
        }

        bool isNULL() const
        {
            return !el;
        }

        operator bool() const
        {
            return !isNULL();
        }
    };

/******* methods ********/
    Ring();
    ~Ring();
    Ring(const Ring<Key> &Ring);
    friend ostream &operator << (ostream &o, const Ring<Key> &Ring){Ring.print(); return o;};
    bool operator ==(const Ring<Key> &Ring);
    bool operator != (const Ring<Key> &Ring);
    Ring<Key> &operator = (const Ring<Key> &Ring);
    Ring<Key> operator + (const Ring<Key> &second)const;
    Ring<Key> operator - (const Ring<Key> &second)const;
    bool insertFront(const Key &key);
    bool insertLast(const Key &key);
    bool insertAt(int pos, const Key &key);
    bool insertAfter(const Key &where, const Key &key);
    bool popByKey(const Key &key);
    bool popLast();
    bool popFront();
    bool ifExists(const Key &key);
    bool isEmpty()const;
    int length()const;
    void print()const;
    bool clear();
    void reverse();

/******* additional iterators definitions *******/
    iterator begin() const
    {
        return iterator(any);
    }

    iterator end() const
    {
        return iterator(any? any->prev : nullptr); // Always check before dereference
    }
};

/******* methods definitions ********/
template <typename Key>
Ring<Key>::Ring()
// : any(nullptr) // Prefer initializers. No need anyway because we did any= nullptr
{
    cout << "Constructor: (Empty Ring created)" << endl;
}

template <typename Key>
Ring<Key>::~Ring()
{
    if (!any) {
        cout << "Destructor: ( Ring deleted )" << endl;
    }
    Node *curr = any; // auto
    if (curr) {
        while(any) {
            this->popLast();
        }
        cout << "Destructor: ( Ring deleted )" << endl;
    }
}

template <typename Key>
Ring<Key>::Ring(const Ring<Key> &ring) // Please be consistent. If you're using 
// capital letters for classes, dont call the variable Ring; it should be ring
// : any(nullptr) // Prefer initializers. No need anyway because we did any= nullptr
{
    if (ring.any) {
        Node *curr = ring.any;
        do {
            this->insertLast(curr->key);
            curr = curr->next;
        } while(curr != ring.any);
    }
}

template <typename Key>
bool Ring<Key>::popLast()
{
    if (!any) {
        return true;
    }
    Node *curr = any;
    if (curr->next == curr) { // one Node
        any = NULL;
        delete curr; // Here is where you "hope" no one copied your class
                     // because you're deleting a pointer that other might be
                     // using, that's what's called a dangling pointer
        return true;
    }
    if(curr->next->next == curr) // two Nodes
    {
        Node *temp = curr->next;
        curr->next = curr;
        curr->prev = curr;
        delete temp;
        return true;
    }
    do
    {
        if(curr->next->next == any) // Last Node
        {
            Node *temp = curr->next;
            temp->next->prev = curr;
            curr->next = temp->next;
            delete temp;
            return true;
        }
        curr = curr->next;
    }
    while(curr != any);
    return false;
}

template <typename Key>
bool Ring<Key>::insertFront(const Key &key)
{
    Node *newNode = new Node; // Either way
    newNode->key = key; // Always set the key

    if (!any) { // Empty
        newNode->next = newNode;
        newNode->prev = newNode;
        any = newNode;
    } else {
        newNode->next= any; // Will be always before the "any"
        newNode->prev= any->prev; // Will always steal any's previous
        any->prev= newNode;  // Any will always point at newNode as previous
        any= newNode; // I'm the captain now
        // Actually, for the above, We don't care if it's only one or more      
    }
    return true;
}

template <typename Key>
bool Ring<Key>::operator == (const Ring<Key> &ring)
{
    if (this->isEmpty() && ring.isEmpty()) {
        return true;
    }
    if (this->length() != ring.length()) {
        return false;
    }
    Node *curr1 = this->any;
    Node *curr2 = ring.any;
    do {
        if (curr1->key != curr2->key) {
            return false;
        }
        curr1 = curr1->next;
        curr2 = curr2->next;
        // No null check needed for non empty rings
    } while(curr1 != this->any);
    return true;
}

template <typename Key>
bool Ring<Key>::insertLast(const Key &key)
{
    if (!any) {  // no elements
        this->insertFront(key);
        return true;
    }
    Node *newNode = new Node;
    newNode->key = key;
    newNode->next = any;
    Node* curr = any;
    do {
        if (curr->next == any) {
            newNode->prev = curr;
            any->prev = newNode;
            curr->next = newNode;
            return true;
        }
        curr= curr->next;
    } while(curr != any);
    return false;
}

template<typename Key>
bool Ring<Key>::isEmpty() const
{
    // return !any;
    if (!any) {
        cout << "isEmpty(): (Ring empty)" << endl;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

template <typename Key>
int Ring<Key>::length() const
{
    int count = 0;
    Node *curr = any;
    if (!curr) {
        return count;
    }
    do {
        count++;
        curr = curr->next;
    } while(curr != any);
    return count;
}

template<typename Key>
void Ring<Key>::print() const
{
    Node * curr = any;
    if(!curr) {
        cout << "print(): (Ring empty)" << endl;
        return;
    }
    do {
        cout << "\t(" << curr->key<< ")";
        curr = curr->next;
    } while(curr != any);
    cout << endl;
}

/******* external function ********/
/****** Example of the split function:
split (r3,r1,true,3,r2,false,6)
r3= 1,2,3,4,5
r1= 1,3,5
r2= 2,5,3,1,4,2
********/

template <typename Key>
Ring<Key> split(const Ring<Key> &source, Ring<Key> &result1, bool dir1, 
                int len1, Ring<Key> &result2, bool dir2, int len2)
{
    if (source.isEmpty()) {
        cout<<"Empty source Ring"<<endl;
        return source;
    }

    if (source.length()==1 || source.length()==2) {
        return source;
    }

    if (len1 <= 0 || len2 <= 0) {
        cout << "split():(incorrect lengths)" << endl;
        return source;
    }

    auto i1 = source.begin(); // typename Ring<Key>::iterator i1 = source.begin()
    auto i2 = source.begin(); // typename Ring<Key>::iterator 21 = source.begin()

    /* I moved second iterator to the 2nd position in original Ring */
    ++i2; // Prefer ++i to i++

    if (i1) {
        for (int i= 0; i < len1; ++i) {
            result1.insertLast(i1.getKey());
            if(dir1) {
                ++i1;
                ++i1;
            } else {
                --i1;
                --i1;
            }
        }
    }
    cout << result1;

    if (i2) {
        for(int i = 0; i < len2; ++i) {
            result2.insertLast(i2.getKey());
            if(dir2) {
                ++i2;
                ++i2;
            } else {
                --i2;
                --i2;
            }
        }
    }

    cout << result2;

    return source; // You *ALWAYS* need to return a value. 
    // This was causing the SEGFAULT (and others like this might also)
}

int main()
{
    Ring<int> R1,R2,R3,R4,R5;

    R1.insertLast(2);
    R1.insertLast(3);
    R1.insertLast(4);
    R1.insertLast(5);
    R1.insertLast(6);
    R1.insertLast(1);

    R2.insertLast(10);
    R2.insertLast(20);
    R2.insertLast(30);
    R2.insertLast(40);
    R2.insertLast(50);
    R2.insertLast(60);
    R2.insertLast(70);

    cout<<"Split function:"<<endl;
    split(R1,R3,false,3,R4,false,6);

    R5.insertLast(10);
    R5.insertLast(20);
    R5.insertLast(30);
    R5.insertLast(50);
    R5.insertLast(50);
    R5.insertLast(60);
    R5.insertLast(70);

    R5.print();

    cout << __FILE__ << ':' << __LINE__ << " I'm alive (no segfault)" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```